# Right hand type assignment

Tags: typescript, react-typescript

I am working on converting a React application to TypeScript and have encountered an issue where a variable is assigned one of two values with differing types:

```
const day = days?.find(d => isSameDate(d.date, date)) || {};
```

If I just put the type on left side like so:

```
const day:Iday= days?.find(d => isSameDate(d.date, date)) || {};
```

I get an error when I try to access one of day's props as {} does not contain said prop. The TypeScript error I get is:

```
Property 'date' does not exist on type '{} | Idate'. 
Property 'date' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)
```

when trying to access `day.date`.

What I want is something like:

```
const day = days?.find(d => isSameDate(d.date, date)):Iday || {}:Iempty;
```

Is something like this possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `union` type, do it like this:

```
const day: Iday | {} = days?.find(d => isSameDate(d.date, date)) || {};
```

Answer (score 0):

A union type describes a value that can be one of several types. Use a `|`(vertical bar) to separate the types.

```
const day : Iday | Iempty = days?.find(d => isSameDate(d.date, date)) || {};
```

Comment: Thank you for a quick reply however i still get the typescript error
```Property 'date' does not exist on type '{} | Iday'.
  Property 'date' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)```
When trying to access day.date

Comment: Can you create a min. repro example. I think your data is `{}` and you are expecting it to be IEmpty

Comment: @Matyno because it doesn't, no. Really this is showing you the problem with your current implementation - {} does **not** have the right properties to replace a day. We can't see how you're using the value, but you'd likely be better off letting it take the default undefined value and actually handling that.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thanks for response, i guess i will have to restructure then to make the code more type robust

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to access `day.date` even when `day` is an empty object, you can use the type `Partial<IDay>`.

`Partial<IDay>` will make all properties of `IDay` optional, meaning that if your `IDay` type looks like this:

```
interface IDay {
  date: Date,
}
```

`Partial<IDay>` is equivalent to:

```
interface IDay {
   date?: Date
}
```

But chances are that this is not the best way to type your code. In your case, it may be better to type your variable as `IDay | null` for example:

```
const day = days?.find(d => isSameDate(d.date, date)) || null;
```

Then you could wrap the code trying to access the `date` field in a condition:

```
if (day !== null) {
   console.log(day.date)
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response,

Setting it to partial will solve my problem but i see that it might not be the best solution,

I think having it optionally set to null with a checker might be the way for my use case.